# gRPC StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: Cancelled in bidirectional streaming service

Tags: android, grpc

I'm creating `Android` application which is using `gRPC` to communicate with server. I have few service methods. There is no problem with communication using simple rpc method but I have problem with `bidirectional streaming`.

I receive one message ServerToClient and afterwards I get error:
`io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: Cancelled`

This is my service:

```
service CommunicationGateway {
    [...]
    rpc CommunicationChannel(stream ClientToServer) returns (stream ServerToClient) {}
}
```

Here's how I create `ManagedChannel` using `OkHttp` and stub:

```
this.channel = OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress(ip, port)
        .useTransportSecurity()
        .connectionSpec(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
        .sslSocketFactory(buildSslContext().socketFactory)
        .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
        .build()
this.asyncStub = CommunicationGatewayGrpc.newStub(this.channel)
```

And here's my code to start streaming:

```
val clientToServerRequest = asyncStub.communicationChannel(object : StreamObserver<Messages.ServerToClient> {
    override fun onNext(value: Messages.ServerToClient) {
        info("communicationChannel onNext $value")
    }
    override fun onError(t: Throwable) {
        t.printStackTrace()
    }
    override fun onCompleted() {
        info("communicationChannel onCompleted")
    }
})
```

Is this problem with my app (client side) or server side? Or how can I check that?

Comment: Did you send out any message with clientToServerRequest? Did the server timeout?

Comment: @user675693 I can send message to server and I get answer for it but after milliseconds I get StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: Cancelled

Answer (score -4, accepted):

As it turns out, it was a problem on server side

Comment: What was the problem ?

Comment: @Tausifmohammad don't know, backend developers fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The Status description you described is likely incomplete. It likely should have been (yes, containing a newline):

```
Cancelled
Rst Stream
```

That's assuming it was generated on the client-side by a modern version of gRPC-Java with the OkHttp-based transport.

If that's the case then the server/proxy cancelled the RPC. No more information is known on client-side.

If you're using a server-side proxy, then it may be killing the stream after a timeout. Check your proxy's configuration.